# Multiple HttpSecurity for different path matcher

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

In my current system, we are using below functionality for Spring Security gateway which is mentioned below.

```java
 http
   .csrf().disable()
   .exceptionHandling()
       .and()
   .httpBasic().disable()
```

but now I want to build a new endpoint which will use HTTP basic auth. How to manage this things using `PathMatcher`?

If we want to use different configuration methods for HTTP basic auth disable or enable. How it will work for me?

When I will use two filter inside same class then I will get below error:

```
Description:

The bean 'conversionServicePostProcessor', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/reactive/WebFluxSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Comment: @Alex I am talking about PathMatcher..

Answer (score 0):

The [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc-webflux-multiple-filter-chains) has some examples of how to do that.

I think you could do something like:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
static class MultiSecurityHttpConfig {

    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)                                                      
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain yourEndpointHttpSecurity(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .securityMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/your-endpoint/**"))      
            .authorizeExchange((exchanges) -> exchanges
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());                         
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain webHttpSecurity(ServerHttpSecurity http) {                       
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().and()
            .httpBasic().disable()                                                  
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

This way firstly your `yourEndpointHttpSecurity` **Bean** would be evaluated if the path matches `/your-endpoint/**` and then your default `webHttpSecurity`